# Displaying single quotes with double quotes in function

Tags: python

I am new to Python and i want to display this message in the console:

```
'print("Hello")'
```

How can we obtain that? is it necessary to do some magic behind?

we can do this:

```
print("'print('hello')'")
```

but the output is this:

```
'print('hello')'
```

Comment: print('\'print(\"Hello\")\'')

Comment: hey @alexander thnks for replying!
I am kinda confused. Why is it necessaary to use "\". I dont get it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character the backlash tells the python interpreter to 'make it part of the string'.  there are other special characters such as \n. try print('hello \n\n world')  i would recommend reading the first 3 chapters of this pdf for general programming knowledge: https://kremlin.cc/k&r.pdf

Comment: Thanks, gonna check it put, pal!